# Error: Element q not found...SeleniumRC in Eclipse...Stacktrace and Code provided..Resolutions pls?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

The below code is the code, which is written for Selenium in Java and which is been tried to be executed/run in the Selenium Standalone server. But, getting an error, for which stacktrace is attached.

```
package package1_IdentifyPageOpened;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;

public class Class1 {

Selenium selenium=null;
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {


selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.portware.com");
selenium.setSpeed("1000");
selenium.start();
//selenium.open();
}
@Test
public void testExported() throws Exception {
selenium.open("/selenium/search.php");
selenium.type("q", "Selenium-RC");
selenium.click("btnG");
}
@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
selenium.stop();
}




/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

**Stacktrace:**

```
com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Element q not found
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:106)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.type(DefaultSelenium.java:317)
at package1_IdentifyPageOpened.Class1.testExported(Class1.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

*Have tried with the browser 'firefox'(browser given in the code) opened and then executing the testcase, and giving a time for the execution of the testcase(i.e.setSpeed-1000), as these were some resolutions, which were provided in earlier instances. But, still couldn't resolve. Help pls..!*

Comment: Post a copy of the HTML surrounding what control you are trying to type into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This URL is not a valid one - http://www.portware.com/selenium/search.php . Selenium opens this URL and checks for the element named 'q'. As the page doesn't exist it dint find the element.

Answer (score 0):

This URL doesn't exist, so selenium is not able to find the element. Please verify your URL.